# Code before Break Statement in Python not executed

Tags: python, break

My Programme is a Mastermind Game, sorry for being such a noob :`)

This is my code:

```
def output(guess, number):
    n=str(number)
    g=str(guess)
    p=""
    if n==g:
        p="Cracked!"
    elif len(n) != len(g):
        p="Enter a " + str(len(n)) + " digit number."
    else:
        for i in range (0,len(n)):
            if g[i] == n[i]:
                p=p+"✔"
            elif g[i] in n:
                p=p+"⭕"
            else:
                p=p+"✖"
    return(p)

import random
turns=0
dig=int(input("Enter the number of digits you want to guess."))
low=10**(dig-1)
up=(10**dig)-1
number = random.randint(low, up)
print("Start Guessing!")
while 1==1:
    guess=input()
    out=output(guess, number)
    print(out)
    turns=turns+1
    if guess==number:
        print("You cracked the number in " + turns + " turns.")
        break
```

And this is my expected output:

```
Enter the number of digits you want to guess.3
Start Guessing!
123
✔✖✖
456
✖✖✖
789
✖✖✖
101
✔⭕⭕
110
Cracked!
You cracked the number in 5 turns.
```

But, this is the actual output:

```
Enter the number of digits you want to guess.3
Start Guessing!
123
✔✖✖
456
✖✖✖
789
✖✖✖
101
✔⭕⭕
110
Cracked!
```

My question is, why is the `print("You cracked the number in " + turns + " turns.")` statement before `break` not being executed? Is it some bug? Or are there some coding mistakes? Please help.

Comment: Isn't it obvious? It's because `guess==number` is not `True`.

Comment: @Selcuk if `guess==number` wasn't `True`, I don't think that the `break` statement would be executed either?
And the programme would want more inputs...

Comment: It is not executed either. Why do you think it is?

Comment: `guess` is a string while `number` is an int. You are doing the conversion in your `output()` function, maybe you should do in the top level code instead.

Comment: Resolved, THANKS :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
def output(guess, number):
    n=str(number)
    g=str(guess)
    p=""
    if n==g:
        p="Cracked!"
    elif len(n) != len(g):
        p="Enter a " + str(len(n)) + " digit number."
    else:
        for i in range (0,len(n)):
            if g[i] == n[i]:
                p=p+"✔"
            elif g[i] in n:
                p=p+"⭕"
            else:
                p=p+"✖"
    return(p)

import random
turns=0
dig=int(input("Enter the number of digits you want to guess."))
low=10**(dig-1)
up=(10**dig)-1
number = random.randint(low, up)
print("Start Guessing!")
while 1==1:
    guess=input()
    out=output(guess, number)
    print(out)
    turns=turns+1
    if int(guess)==number:
        print("You cracked the number in", turns, "turns.")
        break
```

You're mixing up types, there is no way that let's say `"123"` would be equal to `123`.

Example output:

```
Enter the number of digits you want to guess.1
Start Guessing!
1
✖
2
✖
3
✖
4
✖
5
✖
6
✖
7
✖
8
✖
9
Cracked!
You cracked the number in 9 turns.
```